# Installing PIP on Windows 10 python 3.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I just started learning **Python**, and successfully downloaded **Python 3.5**. I attempted to download/upgrade PIP 8.1.2 multiple times using get-pip.py, which I ran (successfully I think) but when I attempted to execute `python get-pip.py`
I got the error code:

```
    File "<stdin>", line 1
    python get-pip.py
        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I understand that pip is included in python but the pip website requires users to upgrade pip which I don't think I can since any pip commands lead to syntax errors, and do not produce the same output that most tutorial sites show. I have tried to find different ways to fix it, but I can't figure out whats wrong aside from pip not being on the computer in the first place or corrupted. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to upgrade pip if you just downloaded python 3.5, go to where you have your Python3.5 file and open the folder Scripts, you will find pip.exe. Open powershell and use the cd command to move to the folder containing pip.exe. From here you can use pip install to get modules.

Open Windows Powershell

```
PS C:Users\you> cd C:\path\to\scripts\folder\containing\pip
PS C:\path\to\scripts\folder\containing\pip> pip install module
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking. If you want to run `python get-pip.py` do it in a windows command prompt, not in the python interpreter. But I do not know why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You already have pip; there is no need to run `get-pip`. Upgrading can be done by pip itself.

But the reason you are getting errors is that all these commands, including `pip` itself, should be run at the command line, not in the Python interpreter.